# How to show only date part dynamically in gridview while using auto generated coloumn true

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to show only the data part in grid view. I'm using auto generated column is true. So I have to write code in rowdatabound. While writing code its giving error saying;

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'string.ToString(System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    e.Row.Cells[3].Text = e.Row.Cells[3].Text.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy);
}
```

Comment: You have to write the closing quote: `ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")`. Please, in the future analyse your code a bit before posting a question here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Text` property returns `string`, not a `DateTime`, you need to parse it to `DateTime` first then you can get it's string representation as `MM/dd/yyyy` format.

I assume your `e.Row.Cells[3].Text` value is a standard date and time format of your `CurrentCulture`, you can use it as;

```
e.Row.Cells[3].Text = DateTime.Parse(e.Row.Cells[3].Text)
                              .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: TryParse would be safer though.+1

Comment: @naveen Sure, that's why I said _I assume_ it is a valid format of his culture :)

Comment: didn't notice that :)

Comment: getting error - String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.i think null values not converting

Comment: howto do null check if date not equall to null then parse

Comment: @krishnamohan What is your `e.Row.Cells[3].Text` and what is your `CurrentCulture` exactly? Can you debug your code and tell us? If you wanna check that `DateTime` is `null` or not, you can use `DateTime?` instead.

Comment: if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text != "&nbsp;")
its worked for null check

Answer (score 0):

you can simply change the select sql statement to get date in required format

```
Select
     convert(varchar,
         convert(date, DateColName, 103),
     101) as myDate
from MyTable
```

or if you using boundfield you can simply use DataFormatString property as below

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="YourDateField" HeaderText="SomeHeader" 
                    DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"  />
```

Comment: gridview insists on showing dates as datetimes, and auto generated columns don't use boundfields.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text != "&nbsp;")
{
    e.Row.Cells[3].Text = DateTime.Parse(e.Row.Cells[3].Text)
                                .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```